# Show fully-qualified Scala type in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Type Info (Mac OSX: Ctrl+Shift+P) from the Keymap will show the short type of the thing selected, or under the cursor, but how can I show the FULL typename (eg. scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U] vs Map[T,U])?

This would be really helpful for figuring out if a collection is mutable or not, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want, but it might help.

You can use `right-click on type -> Go To -> Type Declaration` or `Ctrl Shift B` to go to the place the type is defined.

Comment: Thanks, knew about this, but it is tedious